# This nil instance of a struct, that satisfies the error interface, is not showing as nil

Tags: go

This should be a gimme for someone. Why do I not get what I expect ("Error is not nil") here?

http://play.golang.org/p/s8CWQxobVL

```
type Goof struct {}

func (goof *Goof) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("I'm a goof")
}

func TestError(err error) {
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Error is nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Error is not nil")
    }
}

func main() {
    var g *Goof // nil
    TestError(g) // expect "Error is nil"
}
```

Comment: The best response didn't provide the solution.  Use the reflect package and replace the "err == nil" test with "reflect.ValueOf(err).IsNil()".

Comment: I suggested a different solution (`if err != nil` is everywhere, so I suggested returning a kind of `nil` that works with it), but good point that it lacked any fix. (Just seeing this comment months later, as you can probably tell.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is, it turns out, [a Frequently Asked Question about Go](http://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error), and the short answer is that interface comparisons compare the type and the value, and `(*Goof)(nil)` and `error(nil)` have different types.

Since `if err != nil` is standard, you want a return value that'll work with it. You could declare `var err error` instead of `var g *Goof`: `err`'s zero value is conveniently `error(nil)`

Or, if your func returns an `error`, `return nil` will return what you want.

For more background, here's the start of the FAQ's answer:

> Under the covers, interfaces are implemented as two elements, a type and a value. The value, called the interface's dynamic value, is an arbitrary concrete value and the type is that of the value. For the `int` value `3`, an interface value contains, schematically, `(int, 3)`.
>
> An interface value is `nil` only if the inner value and type are both unset, `(nil, nil)`. In particular, a `nil` interface will always hold a `nil` type. If we store a pointer of type `*int` inside an interface value, the inner type will be `*int` regardless of the value of the pointer: `(*int, nil)`. Such an interface value will therefore be non-`nil` even when the pointer inside is `nil`.

And `==` is strictly checking if the types are *identical*, not if a type (`*Goof`) implements an interface (`error`). Check out [the original](http://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error) for more.

If it helps clarify, this doesn't only happen with `nil`: in [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/AZJntYvMOz), the data underlying the `x` and `y` variables is obviously `3`, but they have different types. When you put `x` and `y` into `interface{}`s, they compare as unequal:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Bob int

func main() {
    var x int = 3
    var y Bob = 3
    var ix, iy interface{} = x, y
    fmt.Println(ix == iy)
}
```